# How do you count the tie-breaking votes?

Tags: voting-systems

For example, there are 24 candidates for senator and only 12 will be declared as the winner. 
Example:

```
...*(other already won candidates)
 9) Candidate A   - 5 (already won)
 10) Candidate B  - 5 (already won)
 11) Candidate C  - 5 (already won)
 12) Candidate D  - 4 (fighting for the 12th slot)
 13) Candidate E  - 4 (fighting for the 12th slot)
 14) Candidate F  - 4 (fighting for the 12th slot)
 15) Candidate G  - 4 (fighting for the 12th slot)
```

Then 7 people were assigned to cast tie-breaking votes. 5 of them voted for Candidate D, two of them voted for Candidate E.

So how do you count these tie-breaking votes? If I count it as it is and add it to the current votes received, this would happen:

```
...*(other already won candidates)
 9) Candidate D   - 9 (fought and won for the 12th slot, but exceeded Cand A's total votes)  
 10) Candidate E  - 6 (got one vote 4+2=6 votes, exceeded Cand B's total votes)
 11) Candidate A  - 5 (Previously won but Dethroned by Candidate D) 
 12) Candidate B  - 5 (Previously won but Dethroned by Candidate E)
 13) Candidate C  - 5 (Previously 9 or/to 11th place but dethroned by D and E)
 14) Candidate F  - 4 (fighting for the 12th slot)
 15) Candidate G  - 4 (fighting for the 12th slot)
```

In your country's election rule, how do you deal with this?

Comment: In my country, elections don't work that way.  Only one winning candidate per post.  In general, this question is too broad.  There could be a hundred equally correct answers.  Please narrow down the question so that there is only one correct answer, perhaps by restricting it to a single locality (country, municipality, etc.).

Comment: Or, alternatively, if you're asking a general voting-system design question (i.e. "How can I make this thing I'm designing work"), that's also valid, but you should make that explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most countries there is an assigned procedure for settling a tiebreak situation, they deal with either *first-past-the-post* systems, an election of multiple people - as is the OP's situation. 
These tiebreakers can assume the form of:
(More popular to less popular)

*A **coin toss** between two candidates or a straw draw with the shortest straw losing*(origin of the saying, 'the short straw')

**Examples:**

Canada, UK (and most ex-colonies inc. USA)

> Canada: In some jurisdictions, a coin is flipped to decide between two candidates for both elections
>   and public service outsourcing contacts.  In 2012 a "one-year contract, worth $171,534, to provide information technology services" was decided by a "best two-out-of-three" coin toss. ([Source: National Post](http://www.nationalpost.com/m/wp/blog.html?b=news.nationalpost.com/news/canada/canadian-politics/heads-or-tails-tie-bid-for-federal-government-contract-resolved-by-tossing-a-coin))

*A **deciding vote** usually made by a chair of some description*

**Examples:**

Canada, USA

> USA: In senate votes the vice-president gets a deciding vote on the issue. It has been used 244 times asofyet. ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tie-breaking_votes_cast_by_vice_presidents_of_the_United_States)) 
>   Canada: Two candidates tied votes in the 1963 Canadian General election tied in the riding of Pontiac Témiscamingue and the returning officer decided the winner with his vote.

**Other**

> Even in Ancient Greek democracy, in the play Agamemnon the goddess Athena comes down to Earth and casts a coloured pebble to vote for a candidate in a tie. 
>   (Source: Greek Tragic Theatre)
>
> Old French law dictates that the eldest candidate should win, but recently it was decided in court that they would rerun an election rather than fall back on the elder candidate. 
>   (Source: FranceTV)